# How can you stop NHibernate (via ActiveRecord) adding this_. to a table name in a formula

Tags: sql, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord which uses NHibernate underneath and I've added a property with a formula as follows to one of my entities:

```
[Property(Formula = "CAST((select count(*) from [User] as u where u.Email = FriendEmail) as bit)")]
public bool FriendRegistered { get; set; }
```

The problem is that now any query for this entity fails because NHibernate adds `this_.` before `User` in the formula. This results in the following SQL:

```
CAST((select count(*) from this_.[User] as u where u.Email = this_.FriendEmail) as bit) as formula0_7_
```

I tried using a different table name just for testing and that worked fine so I guess it only affects tables that share a reserved word, such as "User".

I've tried using backticks to escape it, also tried removing the space between "from" and "[User]", and tried adding the schema (dbo.) all without success.

This sounds like a bug in NHibernate and I found this bug report which is similar: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1617

I guess my question is: Is there a workaround to this or a setting somewhere or even a way to handle this that I don't know about?

We're using NH 2.1.2 and the MsSql2008Dialect Dialect.

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround for this I ended up creating a View called `AllUsers` which just did a `select * from [User]` and then updated my formula to you `AllUsers` instead of `[User]`.

A bit of a hack I know, but this might help others that did something working quickly.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of that JIRA issue, Fabio mentions a `RegisterKeyword("int")` in the dialect, so I'd try adding `RegisterKeyword("bit")` as well.