# How to stop NHibernate from adding "this_." to queries without creating dialect

Tags: nhibernate, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate to query my Oracle 11g database. 
In the fluent mapping files I have a Mapping which looks like that

```
Map(x => x.WaterLevel).Formula("CAST(WATER_LEVEL AS DOUBLE PRECISION )")
```

However, when I run my tests I get

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Due to additional strings (this_.) in the SQL translation:

```
 CAST(this_.WATER_LEVEL AS this_.DOUBLE this_.PRECISION )
```

I have referred to 
    [How can you stop NHibernate (via ActiveRecord) adding this_. to a table name in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752024/how-can-you-stop-nhibernate-via-activerecord-adding-this-to-a-table-name-in)
and [How can I stop NHibernate adding "or this._property is null" to generated queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971048/how-can-i-stop-nhibernate-adding-or-this-property-is-null-to-generated-querie) but the solutions suggested did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reproduce your issue, was to *turn off dialect* setting. Other words, to use the `NHibernate.Dialect.GenericDialect`.

But any of these dialects, is working properly:

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="myFactory">
     ...
     <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
     // or
     <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
     // or
     <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property>
```

So, you do not have to *CREATE* dialect as stated in the question. Just use one of the existing, which is always better choice then generic one...